# CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because it could not read from the physical file

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem in SQL Server when using `create assembly`

> CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because it could not read from the physical
>   file 'D:\CLR\DLL\PersianDate.dll': 50(The request is not supported.).

This is my script :

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY PersianDate FROM '‪D:\CLR\DLL\PersianDate.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
GO
```

Comment: Does the SQL Server Service Account have access to the directory? The error suggests not.

Comment: Saying "you don't know" suggests it does not then. Are you using the default SQL Server Service Account, or an AD one? Is `D:` a physical disk in the machine, or a remote share that you have mapped to `D:` on **your** profile?

Comment: Thanks for replay . my default service SQL server is default instance . (MSSQLSERVER)

Comment: I'm not asking about the name of the instance, I'm asking about the SQL Server Service Account. The account that SQL Server is running under. Don't forgot my question about `D:` too.

Comment: Is that it ? (NT Service\MSSQLSERVER)

Comment: What's the question mark (?) before `D:\CLR\DLL\PersianDate.dll` in the error message. Have you copy-pasted a tab character or something control character-like at the beginning of the file path string?

Comment: That's the default account, so it's very unlikely it'll have access to anything apart from the instance directory. Certainly not `D:` (whatever that is, I'm not asking again).

Comment: I have named the SQL service in my drive partition access, but again it shows the same error message.

Comment: If you still have the issue, try to deploy it using the project created SQL script. You'll probably need to do that for deploying to the server anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Run your code in the server that Microsoft SQL Server installed on it.
And put your dll file in server drive.
It will work.